# Jekyll on Github Pages: any way to add footnotes in Markdown?

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I've recently switched over to using Jekyll on Github Pages for my various blogs, and love that I can just push Markdown to Github and they handle the processing. I'd like to continue using it this way (rather than running Jekyll locally and just pushing the pre-generated site to Github), since the Github UI makes it easy to add and tweak posts if I'm not at my own machine.

There's just one thing I haven't been able to figure out: I can't get Markdown footnotes working. I'm using this style:

```
I bet you'd like more information about this sentence [^1].

[^1]: Well lucky for you, I've included more information in footnote form.
```

I did find one post (somewhere) that suggested enabling a footnotes extension for the redcarpet markdown processor, but this doesn't do it either:

```
markdown: redcarpet
redcarpet:
  extensions: ["footnotes"]
```

Is there any way to use Markdown footnotes without pre-generating the static site before pushing it to Github?

Comment: GitHub Markdown now (Sept. 2021) [supports footnotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69396272/6309). But that would not necessarily translate into Jekyll GitHub pages.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

I use kramdown for markdown parsing and it handles footnotes nicely.

Change this line in your `_config.yml` file:

```
markdown: redcarpet
```

to:

```
markdown: kramdown
```

Comment: @BrockBoland I'm awfully fond of you too.

Comment: Unfortunately, kramdown can mean that code blocks generated by ``` (text here ``` dont' have newlines sorted properly, but I was able to resolve that with three tildas instead: ~~~ before and after the text. This is probably not an issue to most but I had a lot of code blocks like that so a change in the markdown style would have required me to edit a few of my posts.

Comment: Oddly I have markdown: kramdown in my _config.yml file but it never renders footnotes. Very odd.

Answer (score 49):

As of Jekyll 3.0.0, [kramdown is the default Markdown processor](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/markdown/), so the example in OP's question now works out of the box. The pattern is:

```
Some text[^1].

Some other text[^2].

The identifier in the square brackets does not have to be numeric[^my_footnote].

[^1]: Some footnote.
[^2]: Other footnote.

[^my_footnote]: This also works fine.
```

**Update 3rd Jan. 2020:**

- GitHub has its own markdown processor `GFM`, which is an extension of CommonMark. Both kramdown and GFM can be used to render [GitHub Flavored Markdown](https://help.github.com/articles/updating-your-markdown-processor-to-kramdown/).
- Footnotes are [not yet supported by GitHub Flavored Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29384216/8886552), which means the above examples do not render correctly in the **GitHub code repository**.
- Kramdown is still the [default Markdown renderer](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/markdown/) for Jekyll. With kramdown, the above examples render correctly on sites based on **GitHub Pages**.

Answer (score 7):

## Redcarpet

When you want to use `redcarpet` there seems to be no convenient solution right now.
Although [Redcarpet 3 supports footnotes](https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet#and-its-like-really-simple-to-use) with the syntax you've used, it is not included into Jekyll, because Redcarpet 3 removes Ruby 1.8 compatibility ([source](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/pull/1299#issuecomment-20815813)).

### Solution 1: Use forked Redcarpet 2

See [this solution](http://blog.jerodsanto.net/2013/05/jekyll-with-footnotes/) by Jerod Santo:

Add a file called `Gemfile` to the root of your Jekyll folder with this content:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem "jekyll"
gem "redcarpet", github: "triplecanopy/redcarpet"
```

or alternatively [`djui/redcarpet`](https://github.com/djui/redcarpet)

Theny adjust your `_config.yml` to

```
markdown: redcarpet
redcarpet:
  extensions: [footnotes]
```

### Solution 2: Fork Jekyll and include Redcarpet 3

I don't know what's the easiest way to do this. Comments are welcome.

## Maruku

Seems to support footnotes ([source](http://maruku.rubyforge.org/maruku.html#fn:1), [source](http://bloerg.net/2013/03/07/using-kramdown-instead-of-maruku.html)).

Comment: FYI: The `extensions: [footnotes]` works with Jekyll 2.2.0 (I don't know when it was added, though)

Comment: Would the [original Github repo for redcarpet at vmg/redcarpet](https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet) not be the best source to point to?

Answer (score 0):

I found that plugin for jekyll [Github orangejulius/jekyll-footnotes](https://github.com/orangejulius/jekyll-footnotes). May it solve the issue.

Also I read just today an blog [post](https://www.linkedin.com/posts/github_footnotes-now-supported-in-markdown-fields-activity-6849387396979654657-8Zfl) that Github improves the footnotes.

Comment: Yes, that is the post I reference in https://stackoverflow.com/a/69396272/6309