# How to add citation number/tag that leads to same github wiki page reference?

Tags: github, github-pages, github-flavored-markdown

I am not talking about external linking `[Tag](link)` or in-page subsection linking `[Tag](#subsection-header)`. For example, I am writing a scientific paper/blog on github wiki, and same as a scientific paper, I want to give some reference number/tag. If the reader clicks on that tag, that won't take them to an external link or any other subsection, but to the same page and at the end where the citation's reference is mentioned. The citation's reference could be in `IEEE` or in any other format, with/without `DOI`/`URL`.

I googled a bit, but could not find what exactly I want. I tried similar to `[[1](#reference-details-in-lower-case-but-it-is-too-big-and-boring-and-also-did-not-work)]` and at the end give accordingly to the tag line. But it did not work. If anyone can suggest a solution.

### Title

#### Section 1

Hello, this is some text to fill in this, it will lead to the reference [1], is a link to the reference.

#### References

[1] Bi-directional path tracing, Lafortune, Eric P Willems, Yves D, 1993

Comment: I think you want this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25579868/how-to-add-footnotes-to-github-flavoured-markdown

Comment: thanks @ddastrodd, exactly. Dont't knows how I did not find this.

Comment: But one small problem with these, whenever I am clicking on the reference, it is not jumping to the footnote/citation.

Answer (score 1):

After searching deeper on the footnote, I think this approach works somehow by faking the citation number, and `href` to jump the reference number.

#### Section 1

Hello, this is some text to fill in, it will lead to the reference `<a href="#ref1" id="ref1">[1]</a>`, is a link to the reference.

#### References

`<a id="ref1" href="#ref1">[1]</a>` Bi-directional path tracing, Lafortune, Eric P Willems, Yves D, 1993

### Output

#### Section 1

Hello, this is some text to fill in, it will lead to the reference [1], is a link to the reference.

#### References

[1] Bi-directional path tracing, Lafortune, Eric P Willems, Yves D, 1993