# Jekyll link within page

Tags: html, jekyll, kramdown

I'm using Jekyll on Github, and I wonder whether there's a way to link to a section within a page. Say I have a section like

```
## Section 1 ##
section content
```

and later in the same page I want to link to this section. I've found how to [link to another page within the blog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629675/jekyll-markdown-internal-links) and [do footnotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19483975/jekyll-on-github-pages-any-way-to-add-footnotes-in-markdown), but not this.

As a note, I use `markdown: kramdown` in my `_config.yml`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> kramdown supports the automatic generation of header IDs if the option
>   auto_ids is set to true (which is the default). This is done by
>   converting the untransformed, i.e. plain, header text

So in the above example `## Section 1 ##`, it would generate the following id: `id="section-1"`, then the anchor is linked to via the A element:

```
<A href="#section-1">Section One</A>
```

Or in plain kramdown/markdown: `[Section 1](#section-1)`

Comment: Usually you don't need anything else but automatically generated id's like "first-section" for "First Section" section title. Good answer.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that this has been changed to #heading-section-1 (checking on Jekyll 3.7.3 right now).

As a way to figure this out on your own, you can inspect the element and see the id being used on the rendered page.

Answer (score 1):

I found a nice repository that helps add anchors to all headers in three simple steps.

From [docs](https://github.com/allejo/jekyll-anchor-headings#usage):

1. Download the `anchor_headings.html` file from [the master branch](https://github.com/allejo/jekyll-anchor-headings/blob/master/_includes/anchor_headings.html)
2. Toss that file in your `_includes` folder
3. Where you typically would put `{{ content }}` in your layout,
   you would instead use this Liquid tag to output your page's content:

   {% include anchor_headings.html html=content anchorBody="#" %}

As result you will see:

[image]

Which is easy to [customize](https://github.com/allejo/jekyll-anchor-headings#art-customization).

Answer (score 0):

If the section of the page you want to jump to is not a section heading, then this accepted answer didn't work for me. The following worked for me:

```
[jump](#final-solution)


<div id="final-solution"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative that works on my current jekyll static site

```markdown
## My Subsection {#my-subsection}    

This is some content in the subsection.

[Link to the subsection](#my-subsection)
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you put `{: #your-id-name}` on the line underneath anything then it'll make an id for that element and you can link to it.

e.g. a paragraph:

This is some nice text.
{: #my-nice-text}

Will be rendered as:

```html
<p id="my-nice-text">This is some nice text.</p>
```

So you could link to it with link

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).