# Jekyll/Kramdown link within page

Tags: html, jekyll, kramdown

I'm using Jekyll with Kramdown on Github, and I wonder whether there's a way to link to a line within a page. Say I have

```
some line here
```

and later I want to link to this line. If this line were a section then [an ID would be autogenerated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43627485/jekyll-link-within-page). But here it is just a simple line. I tried putting

```
some line here {#idhere}
```

and later link as

```
[link](#idhere)
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the block with a block inline attribute list: `{: id="one_id"}` or the short version: `{: #one_id}`

In your example:

```
some line here 
{: id="idhere"}
```

or

```
some line here 
{: #idhere}
```

and later link as

```
[link](#idhere)
```

Comment: It doesn't work; it just show up as "{: id="idhere"}" or "{: #idhere}" after the line.

Comment: Ok, seems like the ID part just needs to be put on a separate line.

Comment: @user7843034 that's it! Fixed in answer.