# Jekyll links to section id anchors on other pages

Tags: jekyll

I may be searching the wrong terms but I can't seem to find an obvious way to make easy links to page section ids.

Lets say I have a `_widgets.md` file with a section `id=section-1` so I want to generate a link to: `/widgets/#section-1`

I found this for links:

[Jekyll link within page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43627485/jekyll-link-within-page)

So an same page link is as simple as `[Section 1](#section-1)` but I can't seem to find how to add the anchor to links from another page like this `[Widgets - Section 1]({% link _docs/widgets.md%})`.

Comment: I'm not sure that's possible with Jekyll ... or perhaps I just don't understand the question. Could you use an [include](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/includes/)? Something like `{% include widget.html content="https://example.com/" %}` then inside the include you could assign `{% assign url = include.content %}` and then use `[Widgets - Section 1]({{ url }}#section-1)`?

Comment: On the [docs](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/tags/), there is a hint to your concern > Note you cannot add filters to link tags. For example, you cannot append a string using Liquid filters, such as {% link mypage.html | append: "#section1" %}. To link to sections on a page, you will need to use regular HTML or Markdown linking techniques.

Answer (score 1):

One cool way to manage links is to have a central include file that defines the links by name, which is then referenced by each document.

For example you have a file in the _includes directory called "links.md" which defines all the cross-document links in your site:

```
[Section 1]: {% link widgets/page.md %}#section1
[Section 2]: {% link widgets/page2.md %}#section2
etc
```

Then in your markdown you can just say:

```
This is a link to [Section 1] isn't that nice.

... other content

{% include links.md %}
```

Comment: That's super helpful! Though TBH, the real answer is within your answer. Simply creating a link like `{% link widgets/page.md %}#title-of-anchor` did the trick for me. But going the extra step to abstract them the way you did would be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `capture` tag, see [jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/includes/#passing-parameter-variables-to-includes) or  [shopify](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/tags/variable/)

In HTML

```html
{% capture link_with_anchor %}{% link _pages/links.md %}#foobar{% endcapture %}
<a href="{{ link_with_anchor }}" target="_self">Links</a>
```

In Markdown

```markdown
{% capture link_with_anchor %}{% link _pages/links.md %}#foobar{% endcapture %}
[Links]({{ link_with_anchor }})
```

You can benefit from the `link` features (check if page exists) and can add the  anchor, e.g. `foobar`.